# Changing the point an element rotates around

Tags: javascript, css

When I set the transform origin of an element in javascript and then rotate it, it still rotates around the original point from before I changed it and then moves to where it would end if it rotated around the new origin. However, if I wait for a bit and then rotate the element, it rotates around the correct origin. Is it possible to make it so that I don't have to add a pause before the rotation?

```
function complete() {
    var plane = document.getElementById("plane");
    plane.style.transform = "rotateZ(90deg)";
}
            
function turn(move) {
    var plane = document.getElementById("plane");
    plane.classList.add("twisting");
    var target_side = document.getElementsByClassName(move);
    for (let i = 0; i < target_side.length; i++) {
        let cube_face = target_side[i];
        plane.appendChild(cube_face);
    }
    plane.style.transformOrigin = "0px 480 px";
    setTimeout(complete, 100);
}
```

Comment: Hello Bobobby. Could you please include some of you work and code to better address your question?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. I'm making a Rubik's cube and the "turn" function places the 1x1 cubes from the 3x3 cube to be rotated onto the "plane" and then sets the transform origin. The "complete" function rotates the plane after a delay

Comment: `480 px` must be `480px`. No space allowed between value and unit.

Comment: Oops, I just wrote that in instead of the original code to make it easier to read. The actual code adds a class but it's only "plane.style.transformOrigin = "0px 480 px";" at the moment.